# Javascript ' Cannot convert Array to Object[][]

Tags: javascript, json

the last line on the code below return the error message in subject. I have tried many variations but still the same. Data is in 5 columns and 100 rows. I copy pasted the data in online json converter and it comes out fine.

```
  var url = 'https://api.gdax.com/products/ETH-EUR/trades';
  var response3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  // convert to string
  var rawtrades = String(response3);
  //var rawtrades = String(rawstring.substring(rawstring.indexOf("[")+1, rawstring.length-1));

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var first = ss.getSheetByName("trades");
  first.activate();

  var cell = first.getRange("B2");
  cell.setValue(rawtrades);    


  //splitting each block of rawtrades into an array
  var array4 = JSON.parse(rawtrades);

  //copy each element of array3 in 5 columns and rows
  rgMyRange = first.getRange("B10:F109");
  rgMyRange.setValues(array4);
```

Comment: Throw us a bone: What does the data look like?

Comment: Is your fetch implementation asynchronous? If so, you would probably need to wait for a returned promise to resolve before accessing any returned data.

Comment: sorrz, forgot this, it looks lik ethis, i get it with an HTTP request, i show only the first blocks  [{"time":"2017-11-28T12:23:38.977Z","trade_id":957206,"price":"393.54000000","size":"0.33572114","side":"sell"},{"time":"2017-11-28T12:23:18.566Z","trade_id":957205,"price":"393.53000000","size":"0.29670000","side":"buy"},...

Comment: anybody's got an idea ? Looks like the json string gets loaded properly into my array, i can see this in my log, but i cannot copy the content of the array to my spreadsheet:  [{side=buy, trade_id=984567, size=0.00554633, price=406.93000000, time=2017-11-29T18:36:48.484Z}, {side=buy, trade_id=984566, size=0.00445367, price=406.93000000, time=2017-11-29T18:35:53.148Z}, {side=buy, trade_id=984565, size=0.01000000, price=406.94000000, time=2017-11-29T18:35:53.148Z}, ...